# Not able to install Camunda-modeler

Tags: software-installation

While installing camunda-modeler on ubuntu16. It gives an error saying "There is no application installed for shared libarary, do you want to search for an application".And when i click ok, it says "Shared library is not supported"

Answer (score 8):

You need in the file property "camunda-modeler" to mark the item "allow the execution of the file as a program." Then run it from the terminal: `camunda-modeler`

To register the program in the OS, you can run the file "support/xdg_register.sh", also marking it executable